# Append n lines up to a certain character in the previous line

Tags: python, linux, bash

Input:

```
[5 8 15 79 5 6  
.  
.  
.   
n 8 6 4 5 ]  
[18 78 18 79 5 6  
.  
.  
.   
n 8 6 78 ]
```

and so on...

Desired output:

```
[5 8 15 79 5 6 . . . . 8 6 4 5 ]  
[18 78 18 79 5 6 . . .  8 6 78 ]
```

I need to convert all the columns up to `]` into a single line and keep on doing so up to the end of the file.

Comment: What is the input exactly, is that an array or some file contents, literal?

Comment: `perl -pe 'chomp if !/]/' test` ?

Comment: It is supposed to be an array but the output of my code gives me the results the way i shown here so instead of one line i get data arranged in six columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you just want to only print a newline if the current lines ends with `]`.  Try:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, match($0,"]\\s*$") ? "\n" : ""}' input
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed ':a;N;/\]/!ba;s/\n//g' infile
[5 8 15 79 5 6  .  .  .   n 8 6 4 5 ]
[18 78 18 79 5 6  .  .  .   n 8 6 78 ]
```

Explained:

```sh
:a        # Label to jump to
N         # Append next line to pattern sapce
/\]/! ba  # If there is no "]", jump to label
s/\n//g   # Remove all newlines (only reached if "]" in pattern space)
```

If you want to make sure that `]` is the last non-blank character on the line, not just anywhere in it, the regex can be changed from `/\]/` to `/\][[:blank:]]*$/`, resulting in

```
sed ':a;N;/\][[:blank:]]*$/!ba;s/\n//g' infile
```